# How does work $∝$ time $\times$ number of machines imply direct variation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

#### [Question](https://gmatclub.com/forum/x-identical-machines-can-make-x-widgets-in-x-minutes-if-each-machine-238806.html#p1841691)

> 1. $x$ identical machines can make $x$  widgets in $x$  minutes.
> 2. If each machine works at the same constant rate, how many widgets can $y$ identical machines make in $y$ minutes, in terms of $x$ and $y$?

#### I marginally rewrite the [avouched solution](https://gmatclub.com/forum/x-identical-machines-can-make-x-widgets-in-x-minutes-if-each-machine-238806.html#p1841924).

> Number of widgets is directly proportional to number of machines and time taken.
>
> So we can write it as $W∝T\times N  \implies W=kTN,\text{ where} \tag{3}$
>   W= number of widgets, 
>   T= time taken,
>   N= number of machines,
>   k= Equation constant (Don't worry about this :wink:).
>
> [...]

I don't fully understand $(3)$. How can we deduce definitely that $W = kTN$? Why can't $W = kTN + C$, or $TN + C$?

Answer (score 1):

Because then it wouldn't be proportional any more. Consider what would happen if $W = TN+C$ (with $C\neq 0$), and we doubled the time taken. Then the number of widgets would be
$$
2TN+C\neq 2TN+2C = 2W
$$
so $W$ is not proportional to $T$ and not to $TN$ any more.

More generally, $A∝B$ means that $A/B$ remains constant (as long as $B \neq 0$). For any specific proportionality relation, you can name that constant. Let's name it $k$, and see where that leads us:
$$
W∝TN\\
\frac{W}{TN} = k\\
W = kTN
$$
and there you have it.

If we *did* have $W = kTN + C$, then one plausible interpretation is that we had $C$ widgets standing around from yesterday, already made.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please clarify your three equations in the middle? Why did you define $k = \frac{W}{TN}$? Why not proceed straightforwardly from $W∝TN$ to $W = kTN$?

Comment: Can you please respond in (by editing) your answer? A chain of comments is more cumbersome to read.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia: Proportionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)), is the following excerpt (I've slightly edited it):

> Given two variables $x$ and $y$, $y$ is (directly) proportional to $x$ if there is a non-zero constant $k$ such that
>   $$y = kx.$$
>   This relation is often denoted, using the $∝$ symbol, as 
>   $$ y ∝ x$$

To put it simply in other words, that is just how proportionality is defined.

An important property of proportional variables $x$ and $y$ is that **their ratio is constant**, i.e. 
$$\frac yx = k.$$

**But why proportionality?** The easiest way (in my opinion) to note that they must be proportional is to consider what we would happen when $N = 0$. That is, when there are no machines. If there would be an added constant, then that would imply that zero machines produced something. That goes against a reasonable interpretation of the problem.